# How to hide nested element when parents width is 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im trying to hide a nested p tag when its parents width is 0. essentially I want the nested p tag to follow the parent as its width approaches 0, as well as when it expands. I'm sure its something simple, thanks for any help in advance.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gqeqjw7L/3/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="floater1">
    <p id="icon">X</p>
  </div>
  <div class="floater2">
    <p>This is a test</p>
  </div>  
</div>
<button>click</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.floater1 {
  float: left;
  width: 0px;
  height: inherit;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  transition: width 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.show {
  width: 30px;
}
.floater2 {
  height: inherit;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 35px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var trigger = $('button');
var deleteBtn = $('.floater1');
trigger.click(function(){
    console.log("hello")
    deleteBtn.toggleClass('show');
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the overflow:hidden; property to `".floater1"` class. So that the p tag will be hidden when the parent width is 0.

```js
var trigger = $('button');
var deleteBtn = $('.floater1');
trigger.click(function(){
 console.log("hello")
 deleteBtn.toggleClass('show');
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.floater1 {
  float: left;
  width: 0px;
  height: inherit;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  transition: width 200ms ease-in-out;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.show {
  width: 30px;
}
.floater2 {
  height: inherit;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="floater1">
    <p>X</p>
  </div>
  <div class="floater2">
    <p>This is a test</p>
  </div>  
</div>
<button>click</button>
```

See the working fiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/davidsekar/7uk9n0ev/

Comment: Wow, that was simple...Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Add the overflow hidden to .floater1

```
.floater1 {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/murtoza/7jusow54/1/

Answer (score 0):

just add these to your css:

```
.floater1 p {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 250ms ease;
}
.floater1.show {
    width: 30px;
}
.show p {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

hope this can help!